# Cannot change the border color of child elements of a form during the loading of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
window.onload{
var form = document.getElementById("contact").childNodes;
for (let i=0; i<form.length;i++){
    form[i].style.border = "2px solid red";
}
}
```

```html
<form id="contact">
<p>Votre nom :                  </p><input type="text"><br />
<p>Votre Prénom :               </p><input type="text"><br />
<p>Votre e-mail :               </p><input type="email"><br />
<p>Votre numéro de téléphone :  </p><input type="tel"><br />
<p>Décrivez votre projet :      </p><textarea></textarea><br />
<p>                             </p><input type="submit" id="bouton_valider" value="Valider" />
</form>
```

I am trying to change the border color of every child elements of a form. But it doesn't work and I do not understand why.

Comment: What is `formulaire`?

Comment: It should be `window.onload = function() { // your code here };`

Comment: [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Comment: @Archer It still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I believe you are trying to do is highlight all the input elements to red.

Your code has the following bugs:

1. The syntax for `window.onload` is incorrect, which is a function.
   Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload
2. The statement: `var form = document.getElementById("contact").childNodes;` will give you all the child nodes and not only the nodes that you want to set their border. This is basically a `NodeList` Array with values of all nodes, which might be element or text nodes.
   Refer: https://javascript.info/basic-dom-node-properties

I have fixed your code and here is the working snippet.
Hope this helps :)

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var form = document.getElementById("contact");
  var inputList = form.getElementsByTagName('input')
  for (let i = 0; i < inputList.length; i++) {
    form[i].style.border = "2px solid red";
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="contact">
  <p>Votre nom :                  </p><input type="text"><br />
  <p>Votre Prénom :               </p><input type="text"><br />
  <p>Votre e-mail :               </p><input type="email"><br />
  <p>Votre numéro de téléphone :  </p><input type="tel"><br />
  <p>Décrivez votre projet :      </p><textarea></textarea><br />
  <p>                             </p><input type="submit" id="bouton_valider" value="Valider" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write your function like this

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var form = document.getElementById("contact").childNodes;
  for (let i=0; i<form.length;i++){
  if(form[i].style){
  form[i].style.border = "2px solid red";
  }
  
  }
})
```

```html
<form id="contact">
<p>Votre nom :                  </p><input type="text"><br />
<p>Votre Prénom :               </p><input type="text"><br />
<p>Votre e-mail :               </p><input type="email"><br />
<p>Votre numéro de téléphone :  </p><input type="tel"><br />
<p>Décrivez votre projet :      </p><textarea></textarea><br />
<p>                             </p><input type="submit" id="bouton_valider" value="Valider" />
</form>
```

Comment: Did you even ran your snippet?

Comment: yes.. I have made an edit.. please try now. it is working @Oram

Answer (score 0):

Not all elements in your array have a style property, so make sure to check for it before applying :)

```
var form = document.getElementById("contact").childNodes;
for (let i=0; i<form.length;i++){
    if (form[i].style) {
        form[i].style.border = "2px solid red";    
    }
}
```